# Can't get text value from dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

Building off an earlier question...I've built a dropdown that successfully adds table headers to the list, and selects the first item. I need to use the text value in the drop to change formulas, but the dropdown always seems to have a value of 0.

```
'earlier in a separate subroutine
Dim combo As Object
Set combo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AdvStats").Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
                                          Left:=Cells(1, tCols + 2).Left, _
                                          Top:=Cells(1, tCols + 2), _
                                          Width:=200, _
                                          Height:=Cells(1, tCols + 2).Height)
'some code to populate dropdown
combo.ControlFormat.ListIndex = 1 'this works, thanks @SJR
combo.name = "top25Select"
combo.OnAction = "top25Select_Change"
' end earlier code

Sub top25Select_Change()

    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheets("AdvStats").ListObjects("AdvStatsTable")

    With tbl.DataBodyRange
        tRows = .Rows.Count
        tCols = .Columns.Count
    End With

    Dim combo As Object
    Set combo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AdvStats").Shapes("top25Select")

    Range(Cells(3, tCols + 2), Cells(27, tCols + 2)).Formula = "=Row() - 2"
    'Range(Cells(3, tCols + 3), Cells(27, tCols + 3)).Formula = "=" & howeverIReferenceTheValue & "" 
'this is where i'd like to use the dropdown text value, but combo.controlformat.value is always 0, and list property isn't available

End Sub
```

The dropdown change does trigger top25Select_Change(), just stuck on getting the text value. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

Edit: I've used this as a workaround:

```
Dim message As Variant
message = combo.ControlFormat.Value
```

Then I've got an integer which I can use to reference the cell where I pull it from. It works for my needs, but not sure if it's the best solution.

Comment: A quick review says remove the quote marks from the following statement `combo.OnAction = "top25Select_Change"`

Comment: The .OnAction does require quotes (just tested). My code does reach the change subroutine, just can't figure out how to reference the text value

Comment: If "getting the text value" means to return what your combo displays after an item selection, you should use: `"Your text" =Worksheets("AdvStats").OLEObjects("top25Select").Object.Value`. If not, I would like you to better define this term...

Comment: That's a better way to put what I'm trying to get @FaneDuru, thanks! That's what I was looking for!

Comment: OK. I will make it answer. If it answered your question, maybe you will vote it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activeX combo value can be returned using:

`"Your text" =Worksheets("AdvStats").OLEObjects("top25Select").Object.Value`

Comment: Please add an explanation to describe **how** your code solves the issue.

Comment: Simple: His problem was that he **"just stuck on getting the text value"**. My comment was "If 'getting the text value'" means to return what your combo displays after an item selection, you should use: `"Your text" =Worksheets("AdvStats").OLEObjects("top25Select").Object.Value`. And he answered: **" @FaneDuru, thanks! That's what I was looking for! "**. Wouldn't it be enough?